# How to display my html page in mail box

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$to      = 'abc@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$message = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/newsletter.html');
$headers = 'From: xyz@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: xyz@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

This in my mail code. Here I am sending my newsletter to my existing customer.

Can anyone help me how can I send/open the newsletter as the page through mail ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"send/open the newsletter as the page"*? You want to show what's inside `http://domain.com/newsletter.html` as the content? Why not just make a link to that page instead, instead of fetching content? Plus, have you tried it, gotten error messages?

Comment: actually i need need to send monthly newsletter to my existing costumers.. It should be displaying like a page as we display in the browser..

Comment: Keep in mind that CSS support in email readers is (probably intentionally) very limited: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ - so if it works in a regular browser, it may or may not work in an email reader.

Comment: @jsalonen That's a very good point. +1

Comment: @user3530708 You just forget the concate operator in your code for `$header` tag you replace the exist value of `$header` variable
`$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers **.**= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the following, yet you won't be able to use an `http://` call, because this goes against security reasons.

By doing so, anyone could include whatever they want from whatever website. The file must reside on your server in order for the following to work.

Making use of the [`include()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) functions.

You must use a relative path to the file you wish to include.

```
<?php

ob_start();
include 'file.xxx';
$message = ob_get_clean();

$to= 'email@example.com';

$subject = 'the subject';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: email@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: email@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "Message sent.";
}

else{
    echo "There was a problem. Check your logs.";
}

?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

I quote `jsalonen` from a comment: *"Keep in mind that CSS support in email readers is (probably intentionally) very limited: campaignmonitor.com/css - so if it works in a regular browser, it may or may not work in an email reader."*

- Most Email clients such as Google will ignore CSS, so it's best to use inline CSS.

**Images:**

Another thing you will need to do is, if you are using images, then that's where you will need to use an `http://` call to the image location(s).

I.e.: `<img src="http://www.example.com/images/image_1.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

if allow_url_fopen is available in the ini file, you can do this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/newsletter.html');
$message = $html;
```

The reason this should work is because most email clients can read emails sent as HTML (as long as you're sending emails as HTML and not just plaintext emails).

You can use `echo htmlspecialchars($html);` to see what HTML you're sending.

Comment: http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_fopen.html

Here's some information on allow_url_fopen.

Comment: sorry,its not working it is just showing the code.. but my requirement is to display the page

Comment: Oh whoops I think you don't want to use htmlspecialchars. My mistake.